# using pandas to create a multi-tile multi-series scatter chart

Tags: python, pandas, plot, scatter, tiling

Consider the following sample data frame:

```
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=72, freq='H')
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'cat': list('ABCD'*int(len(rng)/4)),
        'D1': np.random.randn(72),
        'D2': np.random.randn(72),
        'D3': np.random.randn(72),
        'D4': np.random.randn(72)
    }, index=rng)
```

I'm looking for an idiomatic way to scatter-plot this as following:

1. 4 subplots (tiles), one for each category `(A, B, C, or D)`
2. each D series plotted in its own color

I can do this with a bunch of filtering and for-loops, but I'm looking for a more compact pandas-like way.

Comment: can you add reference lengthy code to understand what you want it to look like?

Comment: What is the x-axis?  the date index?

Answer (score 1):

This is my guess at what you want.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(8, 6), sharex=True, sharey=True)

for i, (cat, g) in enumerate(df.groupby('cat')):
    ax = axes[i // 2, i % 2]
    for j, c in g.filter(like='D').iteritems():
        c.plot(ax=ax, title=cat, label=j, style='o')
    ax.legend(loc='best', fontsize=8)

fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this the outcome I want and it's is very similar to the code I have with nested for-loops and filtering (as I mentioned in my question).  Is this the most minimalist one can go with pandas? Can `plot`'s `by` argument be leveraged for multi-tiles?  Can `scatter` be made recognize columns as series?